# How to redirect only 2 pages?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my blog site there are almost 150 pages and I need to redirect only 2 pages to another websites's pages. I don't need a rewrite rule but I need to redirect ONLY these 2 pages.

I tryed this but doesn't work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule http://www.site1.com/aaa.php http://www.site2.com/111.php [R=301,L]
</IfModule> 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule http://www.site1.com/bbb.php http://www.site2.com/222.php [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

why ?

Comment: so, does the code below answers your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first argument of rewriteRule is the path not full Uri

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^aaa\.php$ http://www.site2.com/111.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^bbb\.php$ http://www.site2.com/222.php [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```